# a project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly VB.NET

Tags: vb6, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

currently, my boss assign a task which convert VB to VB.NET.

one of my program has occur an error and it.
did anyone come across before? how to solve it and why this error occur?

i know my information is not enough, plz tell me what information u need.
My program contain Designer folder which including .Dsr document(its relate crystal report).
Thx

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/mtcmuc/WindowsLiveWriter/SpicIEHowtodebugtraceaSpicIEplugin_55F9/image_6.png))</sub>

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in the message?

Comment: hi, i tried find the solution in google, the solution like that http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mtcmuc/archive/2009/03/31/spicie-a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly.aspx  but i can not find the exe in my bin folder.

Comment: No googling requried. The solution is presented to you in the message, the picture of which you posted. Have you tried doing it?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand

Comment: did you mean add an excutable project?

Comment: Yes, you have to add an EXE project.

Comment: This is tagged VB6 and vb.net - from the screen shot I assume this should be vb.net?

Comment: Yes, it is.=] i converted from vb6 to vb2010 and then occur this error

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you can't just "start" a library project, you need to start something that creates an object hosted in the library.

This can be a test exe project, a 3rd party executable or test host. You just need to specify something to run. When this starts, the debugger will kick in when the objects are created.